# Connection between central factorial numbers and the Stern–Brocot tree

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Consider the [*central factorial numbers of even indices*](https://oeis.org/A036969) formed by
$$U(n,k)=\frac1{(2k)!}\sum_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^i\binom{2k}i(k-i)^{2n}.$$
Let $u(n,k):=U(n,k)\mod 2$. Define the triangle of numbers
$$A(r,j)=\sum_{k=1}^{2^{r-1}+j}u(2^{r-1}+j,k) \qquad \text{for $j=1,2,\dots,2^{r-1}$}.$$
**Examples.** The few rows are
$$\begin{cases} 2 \\ 3 & 3 \\ 4&5&5&4 \\ 5&7&8&7&7&8&7&5 \\
.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.   
\end{cases}$$

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? The entries $A(r,j)$, for $1\leq j\leq2^{r-1}$, are the newly-added (from the previous row) denominators in the $r$-th row in the [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree)?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that you can substitute the Stirling numbers of the second kind for $U$, since the difference between the recurrence $U(n, k) = U(n-1, k-1) + k^2 U(n-1, k)$ and the recurrence $S_2(n, k) = S_2(n-1, k-1) +  k S_2(n-1, k)$ disappears in characteristic 2.

Comment: Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted earlier in a comment, you can substitute the Stirling numbers of the second kind for $U$, since the difference between the recurrence $U(n,k) = U(n-1,k-1) + k^2 U(n-1,k)$ and the recurrence $S_2(n,k) = S_2(n-1,k-1) + k S_2(n-1,k)$ disappears $\bmod 2$.

But then Dilcher, K. and Stolarsky K.B. (2007), [A polynomial analogue to the Stern sequence](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ereznick/Dilcher-Stolarsky1.pdf), Int. J. Num. Th., 3(01), 85-103, attributes the result in terms of Stirling numbers to Carlitz, L. (1960), [Single variable Bell polynomials](https://www.raco.cat/index.php/CollectaneaMathematica/article/download/57521/67488), Collect. Math. 14, 13–25.